# Cannot edit images under 50x50 pixels

Tags: android, message, wallpaper

When I try to set wallpapers on desktop i get this message. Why? And how to remove this message?

[image]

My code:
-when click button:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();                                                     
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);                                      
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);                                      
intent.setDataAndType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, "image/*");          
intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/*");                                           
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select service:"), position);
```

then onActivityResult:

```
@Override                                                                      
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);                     

    resultView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);                                   
    Bitmap bitmap = resultView.getDrawingCache();                              
    new TaskSetWallpaper(GalleryActivity.this).execute(bitmap);                
}
```

and inner class for set wallpaper:

```
public class TaskSetWallpaper extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap>                              
{                                                                                                  
    private Context context;                                                                       
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;                                                                

    TaskSetWallpaper(Context context)                                                              
    {                                                                                              
        this.context = context;                                                                    
    }                                                                                              

    @Override                                                                                      
    protected void onPreExecute()                                                                  
    {                                                                                              
        super.onPreExecute();                                                                      
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);                                                     
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.crop__wait);                                          
        pDialog.setMessage(text);                                                                  
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);                                                           
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);                                                              
        pDialog.show();                                                                            
    }                                                                                              

    @Override                                                                                      
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps)                                             
    {                                                                                              
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()); 
        try                                                                                        
        {                                                                                          
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmaps[0]);                                                
        } catch (IOException e)                                                                    
        {                                                                                          
            e.getMessage();                                                                        
        }                                                                                          
        return null;                                                                               
    }                                                                                              

    @Override                                                                                      
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap)                                                    
    {                                                                                              
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);                                                               
        pDialog.dismiss();                                                                         
        CharSequence text = getText(R.string.set_wlp_toast);                                       
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);                           
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);                                                    
        toast.show();                                                                              
    }                                                                                              
}
```

Please give me advices

Edited, add logs:

```
04-26 12:40:20.687 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.nico.testwalpapers-2/lib/arm
04-26 12:40:20.691 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-26 12:40:20.796 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
04-26 12:40:20.997 18396-18467/com.nico.testwalpapers D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
04-26 12:40:21.082 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers W/Settings: Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
04-26 12:40:21.124 18396-18467/com.nico.testwalpapers I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:379>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/21/15, 369a2ea, I96aee987eb
04-26 12:40:21.130 18396-18467/com.nico.testwalpapers I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-26 12:40:21.200 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
04-26 12:41:15.491 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers D/GalleryActivity: **onCreate
04-26 12:41:23.033 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers D/GalleryActivity: **click tp set wallpaper button
04-26 12:41:27.681 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers D/GalleryActivity: **onPreExecute
04-26 12:41:27.741 18396-19626/com.nico.testwalpapers D/GalleryActivity: **doInBackground
04-26 12:41:28.491 18396-18396/com.nico.testwalpapers D/GalleryActivity: **onPostExecute
```

Comment: `Please give me advices` Please give us a logcat

Comment: @nicolas are you using `OnePlus` phone?

Comment: @Rotwangin - log nothing doesn't show unfortunately

Comment: @Enzokie - I use LGE Nexus 5, api 23

Comment: @nicolas I am positive that it is a framework bug, I suggest find another library instead.

Comment: @Enzokie ok I'll try, thanks!

Comment: Why downvote? Something was unclear in my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this may be it works for you.
I solved this issue by following solution :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
//add below two line
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
```